# Adding constraints to tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, key, constraints

I'm creating a db for a theater. It currently has only two tables: shows and movies.

Each movie has (besides the auto increment id int not null), a unique string id (also not null), which I would like to use as a foreign key inside of the shows table. Its giving me:

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Here is my query:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DROP TABLE movies CASCADE;
DROP TABLE shows CASCADE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

CREATE TABLE movies (
  `movies_id` INT auto_increment,
  `movie_id` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(100),
  `original_title` VARCHAR(100),
  `punchline` VARCHAR(250),
  `genre` VARCHAR(60),
  `year` INT,
  `duration` INT,
  `url` VARCHAR(150),
  `poster` VARCHAR(150),
  `director` VARCHAR(45),
  `producer` VARCHAR(45),
  `writer` VARCHAR(100),
  `cast` VARCHAR(500),
  `distributor` VARCHAR(45),
  `language` VARCHAR(45),
  `country` VARCHAR(100),
  `localization` VARCHAR(45),
  `plot_outline` VARCHAR(800),
  `sum_of_scores` DOUBLE,
  `num_of_scores` DOUBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movies_id`));

  CREATE TABLE shows (
  `shows_id` INT auto_increment,
  `show_id` VARCHAR(18),
  `date` DATE,
  `time` DATETIME,
  `city` VARCHAR(45),
  `center` VARCHAR(45),
  `theater` VARCHAR(45),
  `movies_movie_id` VARCHAR(18),
  PRIMARY KEY (`shows_id`));

ALTER TABLE shows
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_shows_movies FOREIGN KEY
(`movies_movie_id`) REFERENCES movies(`movie_id`);
```

Comment: Movie_id needs to be a key or part of a key.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys must refer to primary key/ unique key in parent table. In your case, you have two columns movies_id and movie_id, and you have defined movies_id as primary key. But, your foreign key is trying to reference movie_id column. You will need to make this column unique in this circumstance to create your foreign key.